# Stripe's v2 Stripe.card.validateCardNumber() equivalent in v3

Tags: javascript, migration, stripe-payments, payment, credit-card

So I looked around the web and couldn't find anything regarding card and bank validation methods that Stripe had in v2 but in v3:

```
Stripe.card.validateCardNumber()
Stripe.card.validateExpiry()
Stripe.card.validateCVC()
Stripe.bankAccount.validateRoutingNumber()
Stripe.bankAccount.validateAccountNumber()
and so on ...
```

Are there any equivalent methods in Stripe v3 to those above which are from v2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

stripe.js v3 doesn't have those methods. Instead you will create an empty div and mount it, let stripe.js (v3) handle all that validation for you.

For reference, here is the [standard integration in their doc](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/accept-a-payment)